# How to add values from dropdownlist and checkbox to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

EDIT: added a code and a image reference `public partial class DodavanjeNamirnice : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable(); ;
            dtTemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Namirnica", typeof(string)));
            dtTemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Mjerna Jedinica", typeof(string)));

            Session["Data"] = dtTemp;
        }
    }

    protected void BindGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source =.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = pra; Integrated Security = True"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Namirnica";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataTableFromSession = Session["Data"] as DataTable;
        var dataRow = dataTableFromSession.NewRow();
        dataRow["Namirnica"] = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;
        dataRow["Mjerna Jedinica"] = CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        dataTableFromSession.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        Session["Data"] = dataTableFromSession;
        GridView1.DataSource = dataTableFromSession;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}`I got 2 dropdownlists , first one is filtering data in the 2nd,also 1st dropdownlist is connected to sql table as is the other one.
```

I have a checkbox which displays data from another table.
And my problem is: I want to add values I selected from 2nd dropdownlist and the checkboxlist to gridview in my webform.

I tried adding new columns manually but that ends up with displaying only first value from the dropdownlist, also displays only one value from the checkboxlist. 
https://gyazo.com/59ea939b26deb55d3f31e68057249253

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a method to change the selected or created cell into a DataGridViewComboBoxCell and then feed it the datasource of your drop down list.

```
 //could be whatever event you want such as the creation of a new DataRow in your DataGridView
 private void gridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
         dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
         DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
         cb.DataSource = dataSource;
 }
```

You can do a similar thing for the checkbox but new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell() instead. After the user has selected a value you can just switch it back to being a regular cell if wanted.